# sudo apt-get install php5-imagick gives "404 Not Found" error and "E: Failed to fetch ..."

Tags: apt

Running:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

failed, and produced output including this in the middle:

```
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libavahi-common3 amd64 0.6.31-4ubuntu1 [21.7 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libavahi-client3 amd64 0.6.31-4ubuntu1 [25.1 kB]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libcups2 amd64 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libcupsfilters1 amd64 1.0.52-0ubuntu1.2 [74.4 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libfftw3-double3 amd64 3.3.3-7ubuntu3 [702 kB]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libcups2 amd64 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libcupsimage2 amd64 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libjasper1 amd64 1.900.1-14ubuntu3 [129 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main liblcms2-2 amd64 2.5-0ubuntu4 [132 kB]
```

and this at the end (referring to the same errors):

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_1.7.2-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupsimage2_1.7.2-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 5):

Other questions were near duplicates but had different error messages and very complicated solutions, so it seemed sensible to post this question and answer to try to keep things simple.

In my case, it was resolved by simply running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hopefully others will find it's as simple as this too :-)